# Private static final variable inside an enum

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a private static final variable inside of an enum, but I keep getting a compile error.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Syntax error, insert "Identifier" to complete EnumConstantHeaderName
> - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete EnumBody

```
class Foo {
  ...

  public enum MyEnum {
    private static final String MY_STRING = "a string I use in a constructor";
    private static final String MY_OTHER_STRING = "a string I use in another constructor";      

    MyEnumType(1, MY_STRING),
    MyEnumType2(2, MY_STRING),
    MyEnumType3(3, MY_OTHER_STRING);

    MyEnum(int num, String str) {
      ...
    } 
  }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The enum constants need to be the first elements in the Enumeration. A version of your code that compiles:

```
class Foo {

    public enum MyEnum {
        MyEnumType, MyEnumType2;

        public String bar() {
            return MY_STRING;
        }

        public String bar2() {
            return MY_STRING + "2";
        }

        private static final String MY_STRING = "a string I reuse in the enum";
    }
}
```

---

*** EDIT ***

Based off edits made to your original question, I see what you are trying to do. No its not possible to use constants in your enum literal declarations that are declared in the enum definition itself. This is because the literal declarations MUST be the first elements in the enum. This is mandated by the Java Language Specification. Two quick things though:

1. You are using `private static final Strings`. This gives you
   absolutely no benefit whatsoever over using string literals instead,
   which would solve the problem.
2. If you wanted to declare reusable constants (`public static final
   Strings`) then you would need to do so **outside** of the enum.

Alternatively you **can** declare your Enums as nested elements of a class which defines the `private static final String`'s for you.

Some pseudocode:

```
public class Foo {
    public static enum MyEnum {
        MyEnumType(0, MY_STRING), MyEnumType2(1, "Hello");

        private int ordinal;
        private String value;

        MyEnum(int ordinal, String value) {
            this.ordinal = ordinal;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getOrdinal() {
            return ordinal;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setOrdinal(int ordinal) {
            this.ordinal = ordinal;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private static final String MY_STRING = "a string I reuse in the enum";
}
```

Comment: Convention says to put your fields about your methods.

Comment: I'm actually using the strings in the constructor.

Comment: Tom - What do you mean by "put your fields about your methods"?

Answer (score 23):

It is possible, you just have to directly reference the variables.

```
class Foo {
  ...

  public enum MyEnum {

    MyEnumType(1, MyEnum.MY_STRING),
    MyEnumType2(2, MyEnum.MY_STRING),
    MyEnumType3(3, MyEnum.MY_OTHER_STRING);

    MyEnum(int num, String str) {
      ...
    }

     private static final String MY_STRING = "a string I use in a constructor";
     private static final String MY_OTHER_STRING = "a string I use in another constructor";  
  }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome! (and weird)

Comment: I'm getting an illegal forward reference with this, but I'm passing in compiled Patterns instead. An interface nested within the enum did the trick though.

Comment: Seems to compile (weirdly) but then at runtime I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class`

Comment: Compiles but gives runtime exceptions

Answer (score 6):

Interface can be used:

```
class Foo {
  ...

  private interface MyEnumConstants {
    static final String MY_STRING = "a string I use in a constructor";
    static final String MY_OTHER_STRING = "a string I use in another constructor";      
  }

  public enum MyEnum implements MyEnumConstants {
    MyEnumType(1, MY_STRING),
    MyEnumType2(2, MY_STRING),
    MyEnumType3(3, MY_OTHER_STRING);

    MyEnum(int num, String str) {
      ...
    } 
  }
 ...
}
```

Comment: You can nest the interface within the enum if you don't want to have to contain both within another class.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare interface within enum like this

```
enum MyEnum {
    MyEnumType(1, EnumConstants.MY_STRING), 
    MyEnumType2(2, EnumConstants.MY_STRING), 
    MyEnumType3(3, EnumConstants.MY_OTHER_STRING);

    MyEnum(int num, String str) {

    }

    interface EnumConstants {
        static final String MY_STRING = "a string I use in a constructor";
        static final String MY_OTHER_STRING = "a string I use in another constructor";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The objections to the previous answers are 1) some don't work, 2) some don't have true constants, 3) some need embedded or extra classes. How about doing it this way?

```
public class Constants {
    public static final double EQUATORIALRADIUS = 6378137.0;
}

public enum Planet {
    EARTH (Constants.EQUATORIALRADIUS),
```

"But!", you say, "there is an extra class!"
Nope, you just delete the `Constants.class` file after the compile and before the dexing or zipping to a jar.
Or you could Proguard it. In any case you can verify with apktool that there is no reference anywhere to the `Constants` class. All the constants are truly constant and inline with the smali.